# Plotting histogram for column by grouping two column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to pandas and matplotlib. I have a csv file which consist of year from 2012 to 2018. For each month of the year, I have Rain data. I want to analyze by the histogram, which month of the year having maximum rainfall. Here is my dataset.

```
year    month  Temp Rain
2012    1       10  100
2012    2       20  200
2012    3       30  300
..      ..      ..  ..
2012    12      40  400
2013    1       50  300
2013    2       60  200
..      ..      ..  ..
2018    12      70  400
```

I could not able to plot with histogram, I tried plotting with the bar but not getting desired result. Here what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as npy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df2=pd.read_csv('Monthly.csv')
df2.groupby(['year','month'])['Rain'].count().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20,10))
```

Here what I got output:
[image]

Please suggest me an approach to plot an histogram to analyze maxmimum rainfall happening in which month grouped by year.

Comment: please do not use images for your data. Copy and paste your sample data so we can copy it.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your suggestion. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't want to see the `count` per group but

```
df2.groupby(['year','month'])['Rain'].first().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20,10))
```

or maybe

```
df2.groupby(['month'])['Rain'].sum().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20,10))
```

Comment: another option: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6)); df.groupby(['year','month']).sum()['Rain'].unstack().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)` depending on how you want the graph to look.

Answer (score 1):

you are closed to solution, i'll write: use max() and not count()

```
df2.groupby(['year','month'])['Rain'].max().plot(kind="bar",figsize=(20,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

First groubby year and month as you already did, but only keep the maximum rainfall.

```
series_df2 = df2.groupby(['year','month'], sort=False)['Rain'].max()
```

Then unstack the series, transpose it and plot it.

```
series_df2.unstack().T.plot(kind='bar', subplots=False, layout=(2,2))
```

This will give you an output that looks like this for your sample data:

[image]